# Emailing single page pdf file as an attachment from iPad using my own app

Tags: ios, ipad

In my ios app user can send the pdf file as an attachment to some other. It was working on pre ios 7 devices. After upgraded to ios 7 the attachment was missing when app presents the ios mail interface.

Here the code i used to set the mime type:

```
[mailComposer addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"application/octet-stream" fileName:fileName];
```

The above mime type works great on pre ios 7 but on ios 7 it was not taking my file as an attachment. So, i changed the mime type like this:

```
[mailComposer addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:fileName];
```

It was working fine on ios 7 and pre ios 7 devices but the problem was,On iPad if the attached pdf file has single page then it treated as inline image instead of an attachment. This is happening onnly on iPad on iPhone its fine. Also if i send that mail to some one, On the recipient side also it shows like an inline image when they open that mail on iphone or ipad. since when they tap it it allows two option 1. save image 2. cancel. Also this issue not about ios 7 ipad devices this is happening on all ipad devices which was running under ios 5, ios 6, ios 6.1 and ios 7. Any idea how to resolve it?. What mime type should i use for this to resolve it?.

Note:-
for more info please check the attached screenshot[image]

-loganathan

Comment: I believe this is the expected (defined) functionality.

Comment: @Wain, If this is the expected functionality, then any other way to achieve that?. Because my app users wants to send the file(single page pdf or multi plage) as an attachment not like an inline image. Any solution that will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Wain,
I also do not know why the mime type "application/octet-stream" not working on ios 7 devices. It completely ignores the attachment. In ios 7 they expecting the right mime type based on file name?. If the file type is "pdf" then application/pdf and so on.

Comment: Not sure about the mime type change. You could try a binary data mime type. Or make the PDF multi page (which should prevent the preview display, then use the correct mime type).

Comment: @Wain, Genius Scan iPad does it. I do not know how they are handling this issue. They are presenting the email interface with an attachment even the attached file as single page pdf. Any idea on that.

Comment: I am stuck with this problem for days. Did you find any solutions for this? or any other answers worked for u?

Comment: @Suresh, you can use "[mailController setMessageBody:body isHTML:NO];" to resolve it

Comment: Actually I have it like that, but if the user have customized his signature with any hyperlinks/special formats, same problem exists.

Comment: @Suresh, Hmmmm, oh you facing problem there okie. I do not know actually but pdf scanner does it i do not know how they are constructing the data and mime type. just try the pdf scanner ios app

Comment: @all, I tried all the above solution but no luck. I am facing this issue in iOS 11 beta 6, but works fine in iOS 10. I used mimeType as @"application/pdf"

Answer (score 5):

I have same problem with single page PDF. Just change mimeType to **text/pdf** instead of **application/pdf** and it's works.No further change required.

```
[objMailComposer addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"text/pdf" fileName:@"myapp.pdf"];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use plain text message body, the pdf will shows as normal file attachment.

```
[mailController setMessageBody:body isHTML:NO];
```

Comment: I am using this only for now, But i do not know why if i set isHTML to YES not working. Any idea?.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes have the same issue with mail.app on OSX and have compressed the file into a zip file as a workaround. Perhaps that is an option?