# Is addAttachmentData of MFMailComposeViewController broken under iOS 7?

Tags: ios7

I have an App which create an In-App mail with attachment using the following code:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
[controller setMailComposeDelegate:self];
[controller setToRecipients:recipient != nil ? [NSArray arrayWithObject:recipient] : nil];
[controller setSubject:subject];
[controller setMessageBody:body isHTML:isHTML];

[controller addAttachmentData:attachmentData mimeType:attachmentType fileName:attachmentFileName];
```

where the attachmentData is created via

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

// build the file name using the documents directory:
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory, attachmentFileName];

NSData *attachmentData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileName];
```

an the mime type is inferred via

```
    /*
     * Infer the mime type
     */
    NSString* attachmentMimeType = nil;
    @try {
        NSString* fullPath = [fileName stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
        NSURL* fileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fullPath];
        NSURLRequest* fileUrlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileUrl];

        NSError* error = nil;
        NSURLResponse* response = nil;
        [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:fileUrlRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];

        attachmentMimeType = [response MIMEType];
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        // Test
    }
    @finally {
    }

    /*
     * Default mime type is application/octet-stream
     */
    if(attachmentMimeType == nil) attachmentMimeType = @"application/octet-stream";
```

The code works as expected under iOS 4, iOS 5, iOS 6. However, under iOS 7.0 the attachment is missing. Is this an iOS bug or a problem of the above code?

Comment: What ´mimetype´ do you use?
"...the mime type "application/octet-stream" not working on ios 7 devices. It completely ignores the attachment."
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18918247/issue-emaling-single-page-pdf-file-as-an-attachment-from-ipad-using-my-own-app

Comment: In my test case the mime type was text/html. I am using "code" to infer the correct mime type. I will update my question.

Comment: Thanks Vegar. The behavior indeed depends on the mime type: application/zip works. "text/html" does not work.